# Controlling buttons in a .xib from separate controller files

Tags: uiviewcontroller, xib

I'm working on a project that has given me MapView.xib, MapViewController.h, and MapViewController.m.

The .xib has two buttons, which are controlled in the .h and .m files. I need to create separate controller files (ExtendedMapViewController.h and ExtendedMapViewController.m) that will contain methods that control 2 more items in the MapView.xib (a segmented control that can change the map's type, and a button that will hide and show the segmented control).

I cannot figure out how to assign the IBActions to the segmented controller or the second button. Is this even possible to do? I'm fairly new to Obj-C, so even a hint in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i didnt get your question clearly.if u are looking for a uisegmentedcontroller tutorial check here
[uisegmentedcontroller tutorial](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-segmented-controluisegmentedcontrol-tutorial/)

Comment: Sorry it may have been a little screwy in my description (I'm really trying, but I get how confusing it is to me, so...). I would like to be able to add an IBAction to the segmented controller, but in a different implementation file that everything else in the xib is controlled from